# How to fix 'android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5035)' error in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewgroup

I have layout with child (NOT as root) element RelativeLayout and then i create ViewPager and insert it as child of my Relative layout, so it's like

+Relative Layout (root)

|

+-- Relative Layout (child)

|

+-- -- ViewPager

For now moment - all ok.

But then i try add some view item to ViewPager with own layout then i got error

```
10-12 15:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(6031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 15:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(6031): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-12 15:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(6031):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5035)
```

How do that ViewPager will me as Child of RelativeLayout with havin own Child Views?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Problem solved!

It's happened because I call `LayoutInflater.inflate([subViewOfViewPager], [ParentOfViewPager])`

it should be:

`LayoutInflater.inflate([subViewOfViewPager], [ParentOfViewPager], false))`

**More words:**

It's happened because when called inflate with second parameter, view inserting as subchild of given ViewGroup, and then I try add this View to ViewPager. View can have only one Parent ViewGroup element. The third parameter sets `attachToRoot` to false to avoid this.

Comment: Using `LayoutInflater.inflate(resId, container, false)` in a child fragment does the same trick for me.

Comment: @anoniim: This is actually the correct way to inflate, `inflate(id, null)` should not be used since it will ignore all `layout_...` attributes on your layout's root element.

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly what @anoniim recommended and worked.

Comment: LayoutInflater.inflate([subViewOfViewPager],null)  saved my life.. Now i can go home  and sleep :D

Comment: would have never found this discrepancy myself

Answer (score 2):

Simplified version of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12858650/1591934)

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cab_listing, container,false);
    return view;
}
```